# how to call - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i want to call
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` method from my unit test class can any one tell me how to cal....thanks and advance

```
NSURL *urlstr=[NSURL URLWithString:@"mms://notify/StoreActivationData/?%7B%22SUCCESS%22:1,%22FAILURE_REASON%22:0"];

MMSAppDelegate *appDelegate=(MMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
bool valuee=[appDelegate application:mmsdelgate handleOpenURL:urlstr];
```

i am getting this warning: Incompatible pointer types sending `MMSAppDelegate *__strong'` to parameter of type `UIApplication *'`

Comment: Deprecated. Use `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` instead of this method to open URL resources.

Comment: It is because, handleOpenUrl requires application as an parameter, whereas you are passing appDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never call delegate methods directly. Application delegates are designed for using for particular events an application have. Also it'll be automatically invoked at particular scenarios. Never call them directly. It can cause unexpected behaviors in your application.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,in my case it's working fine

```
MMSAppDelegate *appDelegate=(MMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
bool valuee=[appDelegate application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] handleOpenURL:urlstr];
```